# Enable backups of Digital Ocean Instances using Salt Cloud

Tags: salt-stack

I have set up a Salt Master and have got everything to work well but there has been one thing I have not been able to figure out and trying to search for the answer is proving to be difficult so I thought I would see if anyone else has come across this. I have a profile setup in digital ocean that is setup up like the following:

```
digitalocean-ubuntu:
    provider: my-digitalocean-config
    image: Ubuntu 14.04 x32
    size: 512MB
    location: New York 1
    backups_enabled: True
```

When I run the profile it creates the proper instance with all the options correct but the backups_enabled doesn't seem to work. I have tried going on both digital ocean's website as well as looking through the salt documents but I can't figure out if the command changed or isn't supported anymore? If someone knows the answer I would be very grateful to learn what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What version of salt are you using? Do you use the `personal_access_token` in your digital ocean configuration (this will trigger the v2 API)?

Comment: I should have marked this as answered, I found out that there were 2 versions of salt's digital ocean api and I was using V1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt has two versions of their digital ocean API. One for V1 and one for V2. I wasn't using the newer version so there were issues trying to enable new features.